# How and why is a GNAT.Strings.String_List use clause disallowed? How can you use System.Strings.String_List."&" with infix notation?

Tags: ada, gnat, infix-operator

Posting for two reasons: (1) I was stuck on unhelpful compiler errors for far too long for such a simple issue and I want the next person to google those messages to come upon my (or other) answers, and (2) I still don't understand disallowing a use clause, so my own answer is really incomplete.

In order to call a program in two places with mostly the same arguments, I want to use the '&' to append to a default list inline:

```
declare
   Exit_Code : constant Integer := GNAT.OS_Lib.Spawn (Program_Name => "gprbuild", Args => (Default_GPR_Arguments & new String'(File_Name_Parameter)));
begin
   if Exit_Code /= 0 then
      raise Program_Error with "Exit code:" & Exit_Code'Image;
   end if;
end;
```

However, the compiler complains that `System.Strings.String_List` needs a use clause:

```
operator for type "System.Strings.String_List" is not directly visible
use clause would make operation legal
```

But inserting `use System.Strings.String_List` yields:

```
"System.Strings.String_List" is not allowed in a use clause
```

I also got this warning:

```
warning: "System.Strings" is an internal GNAT unit
warning: use "GNAT.Strings" instead
```

So I substituted GNAT for System in the with and the use clause and got an extra error in addition to the original 'you need a use clause for System.Strings.String_List' one:

```
"GNAT.Strings.String_List" is not allowed in a use clause
```

Why is GNAT.Strings.String_List not allowed in a use clause? Section 8.5 on use clauses doesn't seem to state anything on disallowed packages, so is this a compiler bug? Is it possible to define a new package that cannot have a use clause?

Comment: `use type GNAT.Strings.String_List` solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

In a use clause of the form

```
use Name;
```

`Name` must be a package name. `GNAT.Strings.String_List` is a subtype name, not a package name.

There are a number of ways to invoke `"&"` for `String_List`. The simplest is to use the full name:

```
GNAT.Strings."&" (Left, Right)
```

but presumably you want to be able to use it as an operator in infix notation, `Left & Right`. Ways to achieve this, in decreasing specificity:

- `function "&" (Left : GNAT.Strings.String_List; Right : GNAT.Strings.String_List) return GNAT.Strings.String_List renames GNAT.Strings."&";` This makes this specific function directly visible.
- `use type GNAT.Strings.String_List;` This makes all primitive operators of the type directly visible.
- `use all type GNAT.Strings.String_List;` This makes all primitive operations of the type (including non-operator operations) directly visible.
- `use GNAT.Strings;` This makes everything in the package directly visible.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is a design decision. And many other packages in `System` follows this rule. From the s-string.ads (package specification for System.String):

```
--  Note: this package is in the System hierarchy so that it can be directly
--  be used by other predefined packages. User access to this package is via
--  a renaming of this package in GNAT.String (file g-string.ads).
```

My guess why this is done in that way: because it isn't in the Ada specification, but extension from GNAT.

Comment: That and GNAT.Strings.String_List is a type, not a package.